# jQuery count divs and add class after 20

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to count divs and would like to have a class added once it counts 20.
ie: divs 1-20 are class="box" and divs 21 + are class="box new"

This is what I have but it adds the "new" class to all the divs.

```
$(function() { 
    var divCount = $("#content").children(".box").length; 

    if (divCount > 20) { 
        $(".box").addClass("new"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".box:gt(20)").addClass("new");
```

Comment: This is really snazzy. Never knew you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to point out that you can do this with just CSS using nth-child. Of course, if you're using the class for targeting you still may want to go the jQuery route:

```
div.box:nth-child(n+21) {
    ... new styles go here   
}
```

See more here: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var i = 0;
$("#content").children(".box").each(function(i, k) {
   if(++i > 20) $(k).addClass("new");
});
```

or

```
$("#content").children(".box").each(function(i, k) {
   if($(k).is(":gt(20)")) $(k).addClass("new");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that your code says as follows:
*If there are more than 20 boxes, add class 'new' to all the divs with class 'box'.* And so, all the boxes are selected.

In this case, I recommed using the `:gt()` selector: [gt-selector - jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Therefore:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".box:gt(20)").addClass("new"); 
});
```

You can use this cheatsheet if you're not sure which selector to use: [Oscar Otero jQuery Cheatsheet](http://oscarotero.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

if (divCount > 20)

is actually checking a condition for truthfulness and adding a class "new" to all elements that have the class `.box` because the condition passes the test when you have more than 20 divs.

What you want to do is loop through the elements and check for truthfulness of your condition inside that, applying the new class to the current element if it's index is above 20 - 1 (counting starts at zero, so your element with an index of 19 will be your 20th element).

```
$(function() {
    $.each($("#content").children(".box"), function(index, value){
        if ( index - 1 > 20 ) {
            $(this).addClass(".new");
        }
    });
});
```